# Parallel solutions to N Queens Puzzle

Tags: java, algorithm, multithreading, comparative-review, n-queens

I'm trying to increase the performance of my N Queens Puzzle solution. I'd find some threads on SO already but they don't appear to help me to increase performance.

My best solution, however, is a strategy with a constant amount of working threads. I also tried to implement a solution with `RecursiveTasks`. But it appears that the first solution overcomes all my other tries. I think that is because the computer receives too many Tasks and looks for completion of working tasks most of the time.

However, I'd come up with two solutions:

First, the slow one with an implementation of `RecursiveTask` which needs 2449 ms for the calculation of N = 14:

```
public class DamenProblemFork extends RecursiveTask<Integer>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6502127276625965624L;
    static int N = 14;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        if (args.length == 1) {
            N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        DamenProblemFork dpf_root = new DamenProblemFork(0L, 0L, 0L, N - 1);
        Integer result = dpf_root.fork().join();

        System.out.println("End time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
        System.out.println("Result for " + N + ": " + result);

    }

    private long diagR;
    private long diagL;
    private long mid;
    private int depth;

    public DamenProblemFork(long diagR, long diagL, long mid, int depth) {
        this.diagR = diagR;
        this.diagL = diagL;
        this.mid = mid;
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer compute() {

        List<DamenProblemFork> ldpf = new ArrayList<>();

        long valid = mid | diagL | diagR;
        int resBuffer = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int pos = 1 << i;
            if ((valid & pos) > 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if (depth == 0) {
                resBuffer++;
                continue;
            }

            long n_mid = mid | pos;
            long n_diagL = (diagL | pos) >> 1;
            long n_diagR = (diagR | pos) << 1;

            DamenProblemFork dpf = new DamenProblemFork(n_diagR, n_diagL, n_mid, depth - 1);
            ldpf.add(dpf);
        }

        if(depth == 0) {
            return resBuffer;
        }

        return ldpf.stream().parallel().map(d -> d.fork()).mapToInt(x -> x.join()).sum();
    }
}
```

The next solution I'd come up with is with a dedicated thread pool with thread number equal to processor count. This, however, just needs 124ms for the calculation of 14:

```
public class DamenProblem {
    static AtomicInteger result = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static int N = 14;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        if (args.length == 1) {
            N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }

        int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        int availableProcessors = processors < N ? processors : N;

        BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(N);
        ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(availableProcessors, availableProcessors, 100,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, workQueue);
        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();


        if(N%2 == 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < N/2; i++) {
            int pos = 1 << i;
            tpe.execute(() -> {
                int res = run(pos << 1, pos >> 1, pos, N - 2);
                result.getAndAdd(res);
                sem.release();
            });
        }
        sem.acquire(N/2);

        System.out.println("End time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
        System.out.println("Result for " + N + ": " + result.get()*2);

        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                int pos = 1 << i;
                tpe.execute(() -> {
                    int res = run(pos << 1, pos >> 1, pos, N - 2);
                    result.getAndAdd(res);
                    sem.release();
                });
            }
            sem.acquire(N);

            System.out.println("End time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
            System.out.println("Result for " + N + ": " + result.get());
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    static int run(long diagR, long diagL, long mid, int depth) {
        long valid = mid | diagL | diagR;
        int resBuffer = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int pos = 1 << i;
            if ((valid & pos) > 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if (depth == 0) {
                resBuffer++;
                continue;
            }
            long n_mid = mid | pos;
            long n_diagL = (diagL | pos) >> 1;
            long n_diagR = (diagR | pos) << 1;

            resBuffer += run(n_diagR, n_diagL, n_mid, depth - 1);
        }
        return resBuffer;
    }
}
```

My CPU is an AMD ryzen 5 2600K with 12 cores.

Do you guys have an idea how to improve this code to make it even faster? I thought something of including symmetry. But does this work? I think using symmetry just increases performance if N is greater than the number of processors times two.

What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm trying to improve my programming skills and my thinking. :)

Comment: I agree to you that symmetry could improve performance. Might try `for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {` in `main` and then double `result` and run again with `int i = Math.ceil(N / 2)` if `N` is uneven

Comment: @JonasW. nice point, but the Math.ceil is not required :), i update the code in the question

Comment: @noixes yeah im from Javascript :) and did it effect performance? Im curious...

Comment: @JonasW. It did sightly. From about 200ms to 124ms on 14. For 16 its 3740ms now :).. So about half

Comment: @JonasW. Whoups.. I just realized, i could not implement it for uneven numbers as well .. :x.. How would you do that in the else part of main?

Comment: @noixes negative numbers?! How can a game of chess be played on a board with negative dimensions? (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: @JonasW. I ment uneven :x

Comment: @noixes just as i said. You can take the even loop for uneven numbers too, you just have to consider the "middle" row.

Comment: @JonasW. .. yeah, but how do i consider it? I think i miss something in my thought process

Comment: Just take the half loop, then do `if(N % 2 == 1) { int pos = 1 < Math.ceil(N / 2); result += run(pos << 1, pos >> 1, pos, N - 2); }`

Comment: if i do that i get 34 as a result of N = 7, but it actually is 40 .. I have to do    sem.acquire((int) Math.ceil(N / 2)); as well to acquire the amount of working-threads